# Bounding largest eigenvalue

Tags: matrices

Hi all,

do you know how to compute (as a function of n) the largest eigenvalue of this matrix (or at least to bound it)?

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 1 &           &   &  &  \cr
1 & 0 &  \sqrt 2  &   &  &  \cr
  & \sqrt 2 &  0  &   &  &  \cr
  &   &  & \ddots &   &  &  \cr
  &   &  &  & 0 & \sqrt n &  \cr
  &   &  &  & \sqrt n & 0 &
\end{array}\right)
$$

Thanks!

Comment: You can bound it by Gershgorin. out of interest, does this come from some kind of random matrix problem?

Comment: I ask because this matrix is the expected value of the natural tridagonalization of the unnormalized GOE, although that may not be relevant here

Comment: you can bound it above $2\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @Yemon: It looks to me like the sum of a creation and an annihilation operator on (a finite-dimensional piece of) a Fock space in quantum field theory.  Would that have any connection with the GOE that you mentioned?

Comment: The dominant eigenvalue is asymptotic to $2 \sqrt n$.  This can be seen by comparison with multiples of the $m \times m$ matrix, call it $L_m$, whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ if $|i-j|=1$ and $0$ else.  The eigenvalues of $L_m$ are known explicitly and the largest one approaches $2$ from below as $m \rightarrow \infty$.  Kate Juschenko may have used this to obtain the upper bound $2 \sqrt n$ (the matrix is smaller than $\sqrt n M_{n+1}$).

Comment: @Andreas: I am not sure if there is an interpretation of this via operators on Fock space that connects to the GOE via some "natural" or asymptotic correspondence. What I had in mind can be found in Section 3.3 of the unpublished note http://math.usask.ca/~choi/pubmath/part3ess/EssayFin.ps.gz (although it turns out that the same idea was done in an Adv Math paper of Trotter, from the 1980s I think)

Comment: My comment above is not quite right, as I now see from looking at the note I linked to. What is true is that if you take something from the unnormalized GOE then it is unitarily equivalent (via a certain random unitary) to a tridiagonal matrix $T$ whose diagonal entries are iid normal of mean zero and where $T_{i,i+1} \sim Y_i^{1/2}$ where $Y_i$ is chi-squared of degree $i$. So my claim is not true, as the mean of $Y_n^{1/2}$ is not $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: ... however, I think it follows from known concentration results that if you take something from the normalized GOE and tridiagonalise it, you will with high probability get something large-$n$-asymptotically unitarily equivalent to a rescaled version of the matrix in question.

Comment: [Edited only to replace the link to http://i.imgur.com/Wzhzf.jpg by equivalent TeX.]

Comment: This come from physics, it is the representation of the sum of annihilation and creation operators on a bounded boson Fock space.

Comment: @Noam: where can I find a reference for the bounding of $L_m$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you denote $A_n$ your tri-diagonal matrix of order $n$, and  $H_n(x):= \det(x+A_n)$, the sequence $H_n$ satisfies the two-term linear recurrence $H_{n+1}=xH_n - nH_{n-1}$ with initial conditions $H_0=1$ and $H_1=x$. Thus, they are the [Hermite polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) (here in the "probabilist's version"), and their zeros are the eigenvalues of $-A_n$ (on which you can find everything in the literature).

Comment: I'd like to add that the connection with random matrices that Yemon Choi suggests above may be the following : The mean characteristic polynomial of a $n\times n$ GUE random matrix X, namely $\mathbb{E}_{GUE}\det(xI_n−X)$, is actually the Hermite polynomial (this formula goes back to Heine), for which the matrix of recurrence coefficients is given by An, as you pointed out. Even so I don't really see GOE there, even it is plausible. The matrix An is also interpreted as a Toeplitz operator associated with the sum of a creation and annihilation operator as pointed out by Andreas Blass.

Comment:  The connection with such creation/ annihilation operator has been used by Voiculescu once developing free probability theory. I think this is explained in the book of Hiai and Petz, "The Semicircle Law, Free Random Variables and Entropy". I hope this helps ...

Comment: @Adrien: see my comments to the main question for some attempts to correct and clarify my initial claims